# Selenium webdriver 3.3.0 geckodriver error for firefox

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium-webdriver, rubymine, geckodriver

I'm trying to execute a `ruby script` on my Windows 10.

Setup Details:

```
Browser :- latest version of Firefox, <br>
ruby -v 2.2.6<br>
gem -v 2.4.5.2 <br>
selenium webdriver -v 3.3.0
```

Now i got an error that it cant find `geckodriver`. I also downloaded `geckodriver` and added it to the `Path`.

This is the error message that I get:

> Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:  Unable to find Mozilla
>   geckodriver. Please download the server from
>   https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases and place it somewhere
>   on your PATH. More info at
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Did you read the error message? Did you read the links in the error message? Did you follow the instructions in those links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear from the error message which is `Unable to find Mozilla geckodriver` and `place it somewhere on your PATH`

Here is what you need to do:

1. Download the latest stable gecko driver & place it in a folder in "C:\abc".
2. Rename the gecko driver to geckodriver.exe
3. Download and install the latest released Mozila Firefox.
4. Ensure you are using either 32 bit or 64 bit for both.
5. Keep your code like:

   ```
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\abc\\geckodriver.exe");
   WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   driver.get("http://gmail.com");
   ```

Let me know if it works for you.